# What is the difference between these IDs/classes?

Tags: html, css

What is the difference between these?

`#hello-world p 
p #hello-world 
p#hello-world`

If you could give me an example of each that would be the best.
Thanks

Comment: To paraphrase your question: What between the difference these is?

Comment: These are not classes but selectors. Selectors may use ids, classes, tag names, attributes, pseudo-attributes, relationships, etc. None of your selectors use classes, they only use ids and tag names.

Answer (score 0):

```
#hello-world p
```

Will match a `<p>` paragraph tag that is a child (or sub-child) of any tag with the ID hello-world, eg. (div can be anything)

```
<div id="hello-world"> <p>paragraph</p> </div>
```

or

```
<div id="hello-world"> <section id="another-id"> <p>paragraph</p> </section> </div>
```

...

```
p #hello-world
```

Will match any tag with the ID hello-world that is a child (or sub-child) of a `<p>` paragraph, eg:

```
<p> <span id="hello-world">anything</span> </p>
```

or

```
<p> <a href="#"> <span id="hello-world">anything</span> </a> </p>
```

...

```
p#hello-world
```

Will match only `<p>` paragrah tags with the ID hello-world, eg:

```
<p id="hello-world">paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector: `#hello-world p` selects all `<p>` elements that are descendants of an element with an id that is `hello-world`.

The selector: `p #hello-world` selects an element with an id that is `hello-world` that is descended from a `<p>` element.

The selector `p#hello-world` selects a `<p>` element that has an id of `hello-world`.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Yes that helps. And solves it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With this in css: `#hello-world p { }`, you would style every paragraph in #hello-world element. It could be div, span, section or what ever.

With: `p #hello-world { }` you would style #hello-world element in any paragraph on your page. Notice that ID's (in this case #hello-world ID) must be unique and only one element should have the id.

With `p#hello-world { }` you would style a paragraph which ID is #hello-world

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're asking about CSS selectors and which make sense to actually use, you first need to realise that CSS selectors are matched from right to left.

```
#hello-world p
```

This selects every `<p>`-element and all of those are verified to be (somewhere) in an element with the id `hello-world`

```
<p><div id=hello-world><p>...</p></div></p> (matched the <p> inside <div id=hello-world>)
<p><div id=hello-others><p>...</p></div></p> (does not match)
<p><div><p id=hello-world>...</p></div></p>  (doet not match)
```

---

```
p #hello-world
```

This selects every element with the id `hello-world` (which **MAY** only be one element) and that element is verified to be (somewhere) in a `<p>` element.

```
<p><div id=hello-world><p>...</p></div></p> (matched the <div id=hello-world>)
<p><div id=hello-others><p>...</p></div></p> (does not match)
<p><div><p id=hello-world>...</p></div></p>  (doet not match)
```

---

```
p#hello-world
```

This selects every element with the id `hello-world` (which **MAY** only be one element) and that element must be a `<p>`-element itself.

```
<p><div id=hello-world><p>...</p></div></p>  (does not match)
<p><div id=hello-others><p>...</p></div></p> (does not match)
<p><div><p id=hello-world>...</p></div></p>  (matches <p id=hello-world>)
```

---

All of them make sense in a way, and all of them mean something different. Which is best would be up to you and your implementation.

Common sense would dictate the `p #hello-world` and `p#hello-world` to be somewhat odd, as it is basically claims you are not sure where and/or on what element you will be applying the id `hello-world`. If you are sure of its position/id, you should simplify it to just `#hello-world`, as that is what it would match anyway.